# In a field why does the multiplicative identity have an additive inverse, whereas the additive identity doesn't have a multiplicative inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $\langle K, +, * \rangle$ be our field. By definition, we know that every non-zero element, i.e every element except the additive identity, has an multiplicative inverse in the field, and we also do know that every element, including the multiplicative identity, has a additive inverse in the field.

However, giving the fact that additive and multiplicative operations are just binary operations, and they are just represented by different symbols, I would expect both addition and the multiplication to behave in the same way in the sense that if multiplicative identity has an additive inverse, so should the additive inverse to have a multiplicative inverse, i.e a symmetry between them.

So my question is exactly which property of those binary operations or the proper of the field is corresponds to this unsymmetrical behaviour ?

Comment: There is no symmetry because of the distributive law, which holds only in the form $a(b+c) = ab + ac$ and not $a+bc = (a+b)(a+c)$. From this identity and the group axioms for $+$, as well as the fact that $0\neq 1$ you can dedice that $0$ has no multiplicative inverse. Now why do we want this identity to hold in a field (ring more generally) ? Simply because rings are meant to generalize $\mathbb{Z}$ and other common structures ans it turns out that distributivity is essential in those structures to get anything done

Comment: @Max I advised you to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: In a ring the zero element is absorbing, since $0r= (r-r)r = r^2-r^2=0$.

Comment: @Wuestenfux Please read my question again, and then read your comment.

Comment: Hmm. There is no number $r$ with $0r=1$. This is the consequence of my comment.

Comment: @Wuestenfux I'm asking that why the zero doesn't have an inverse, I'm asking that although the multiplicative identity, $e$, have additive inverse, due to what property doesn't the additive identity, $0$,  have a multiplicative  inverse, since multiplication and addition are just symbols for an abstract binary operations.

Comment: Actually, @Max's comment is the answer to my question.

Comment: @onurcanbektas But multiplication and addition are *not just* symbols for two abstract binary operations. They are symbols for two abstract binary operations *that satisfy certain axioms*. And, as it happens, the field axioms do *not* treat $+$ and $\cdot$ symmetrically; if we swap the two symbols, we do *not* get an equivalent set of axioms. (On the other hand, in Boolean algebra, the symbols for AND and OR *are* treated symmetrically, and so we have a *duality principle*.)

Comment: This is tangentially related, but this question reminds me of the exercise "which fields have multiplicative group isomorphic to their additive group?"

Comment: @MarkS. Nice question, but do you have in mind a specific answer to that question ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas I know the answer, but it is a cute exercise to do from the definitions that is best enjoyed without the hint of the answer to the question. If you already know the definitions of additive group and multiplicative group and isomorphisms of groups, but get stuck trying to solve it, you can post a question here on MSE showing what you tried. If you really just want the answer and don't want to solve it, you can google and find a discussion of a solution - I believe this problem may be in Dummit and Foote

Comment: @MarkS. Ok, I'm going to think on it, thanks for letting us know that question by the way :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As I said in the comments, the symmetry is broken because of the distributivity, $a(b+c) = ab + ac$, which does not hold symmetrically (indeed $a+bc = (a+b)(a+c)$ is not true in general).

This identity, the group axioms for $+$ and the fact that $0\neq 1$ altogether imply that $0$ has no multiplicative inverse ($0a = (0+0)a = 0a + 0a$ and so $0a=0$, so unless $0=1$, $0$ has no inverse)

These axioms are there to generalize $\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q}$ (integral domains, or more generally rings with more than one element), and are therefore "natural", because in particular distributivity is essential in those structures.

Comment: So, If we create a new algebraic structure similar to field with including the distribution of addition over multiplication, i.e $a + bc = (a+ b)(a+c)$, would zero have an inverse ?

Comment: In mathematics, the phenomena come first, and the definitions come afterwards. It's not the other way around. To put things somewhat differently, mathematics is not a game in which we make definitions up out of nothing, and then see where they lead.

Comment: No, the same proof would still go, as long as every element has an additive inverse. But if you completely remove "classical" distributivity and add your new axiom, then zero could possibly have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: @Lubin You sounded like one of my physics professors.

Comment: @onurcanbektas: If you just _add_ that to the ring or field axioms, you would be able to prove that $x=x+0=x+0\cdot(-x)=(x+0)(x-x) = x\cdot 0 = 0$ for every $x$, so your structure would be rather uninteresting.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yeah, I didn't see that coming, thanks for pointing out :).

Answer (score 1):

It's because $$0r=(r-r)r=r^2-r^2=0,$$ so if $0r=1,$ we would have $0=1$, a contradiction.

Comment: See the comments https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2375545/in-a-field-if-we-have-additive-inverse-for-the-multiplicative-identity-why-don/2375590#comment4896860_2375545

Comment: @onurcanbektas: That link just goes back to this answer.

Comment: @jwodder As I have said, see the comments below the question, the links will direct you to those comments.

Comment: @onurcanbektas That link doesn't go to any comments; it goes to this answer.

Comment: @jwodder https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2375545/in-a-field-why-does-the-multiplicative-identity-have-an-additive-inverse-wherea/2375590#comment4896860_2375545

Comment: @jwodder You don't need a link actually, just look at the comment below the main question.